# Slow performance when testing non-local IP services with Playwright

Tags: testing, playwright, e2e

[image:network logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HClAr.png)  When using Playwright (version 1.42.1) to test services hosted on the local machine using localhost or 127.0.0.1 with Chrome 108 and Chromium 100 browsers on Windows 7 Professional, the testing process is fast. However, when testing services hosted on the local machine's IP address (e.g., 10.132.xxx.xxx) or other IP addresses within the same intranet, the testing process becomes significantly slower.

my code:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
test('test', async ({page }) => {
  await page.goto('http://10.13.xxx.xxx:8080/test');
  await page.getByRole('button', {name: "Login"}).click()

  await page.waitForTimeout(5000);

});
```

Services can be any web project, such as a simple project containing multiple JavaScript files, Vue projects, etc

Environment:
Playwright Version: 1.42.1
Operating System: Windows 7 Professional
Browsers: Chrome 108, Chromium 100
Network Condition: Intranet environment

Playwright should be able to test services within the same intranet environment, including those hosted on the local machine's IP address, with similar performance as testing services using localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]? I don't think anyone can look at this post, which is basically a few OS specs, and be able to provide a solution. The problem is likely something to do with your particular code. If it's not the code, then please provide the simplest code that reproduces the issue anyway so it helps eliminate any speculation that the code is at fault. Thanks.

Comment: yes，I have added the code and network log screenshots

Comment: http://10.13.xxx.xxx:8080/test is not a thing I can access. The question basically says "Playwright runs slower on an intranet than localhost" and that's about it. What steps can someone take to reproduce this?

Comment: It can be any service. My project is in an intranet environment and cannot be hosted externally. When I use the local intranet IP address, the loading of resources such as JavaScript and CSS is very slow, while using localhost is much faster. There is a long delay between the loading of each resource, as shown in the 'Start' column in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by adding the startup parameters --proxy-server='direct://' --proxy-bypass-list=*, although I am not sure of the exact reason.